# How to extract string line by line from one text file to another text file

Tags: php

I have a text file of phone numbers like below:

> +2348089219281 +2348081231580  +2347088911847  +2347082645764  +2348121718153  +2348126315930  +2348023646683.

I want to extract each number, strip `+234` from it and replace with `0` , then add the following text `"Names" . "\t"` in front of the modified number.

Then I want to insert this new string in a new text file (line-by-line)..
This is what I get in the new_textFile with the code I've wrote:

> Names  00urce id #3
>
> Names  00urce id #3

Here's my code:

```
$this_crap_file = fopen($old_file_name, "r");
$total_number_lines_for_this_crap_file = count($this_crap_file);
while(!feof($this_crap_file))
{
  $the_new_writing = fopen($new_file_name, "a");
  $the_string = substr_replace($this_crap_file, "0", 0, 4);
  $new_string = "Names" . "\t" . 0 . $the_string . "\n";
  fwrite($the_new_writing, $new_string);
}
fclose($this_crap_file);
```

Comment: You don't seem to be reading from the file at all. Use `fgets` to read lines from the file.

Comment: You should move the fopen() line that opens the new file to just before the while loop.  As it is now, you're opening the new file on each and every iteration through the loop.

Comment: a start? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fNz click preg_replace

Comment: @Brian Showalter: There's no space between fopen and the parenthesis.

Comment: @apokryfos: I tried fgets got error message saying parameter 1 should a resource instead of a string.

Comment: @Andreas: phpliveregex.com doesn't solve the problem of fetching the strings line by line.
But thanks all for your contributions

Comment: @Wasiu I said "start". But why is it so important to read it line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No space between fopen and the parenthesis? Sorry, I don't see the relevance of that statement.

Assuming your input file only has one phone number per line, and that they all start with '+234', you could use a regular expression to pick out just the part you want to put in the new file, like this:

```
$this_crap_file = fopen($old_file_name, "r");
$the_new_writing = fopen($new_file_name, "a");

while ($line = fgets($this_crap_file))
{
  preg_match('/\+234(\d+)/', $line, $matches);
  $new_string = "Names\t" . $matches[1] . "\n";
  fwrite($the_new_writing, $new_string);
}

fclose($the_new_writing);
fclose($this_crap_file);
```

Comment: This also fixes the problem that `$new_file_name` should be opened once rather than on each iteration to prevent aggressive allocation-deallocation of resources.

Comment: @Brian Showalter:
Yes, it works! Thanks.
I've never handled files before. Now I get it. 
I'm going to read up on regular expression.
I want to pick your last post as answer but I only see rating buttons.